# how to creat a subset of sample from original size of mnist data, while keeping all 10 classes

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, mnist, numpy-ndarray

suppose `X,Y = load_mnist()` where X and Y are the tensors that contain the whole mnist. Now i want a smaller proportion of the data to make my code run faster, but i need to keep all 10 classes there and also in a balanced manner. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scikit-learn's `train_test_split` is meant to split the data into train and test classes, but you can use it to create a "balanced" subset of your dataset using the `stratified` argument. You can just specify the train/test size proportion you desire and thereby obtain a smaller, stratified sample of your data. In your case:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_1, X_2, Y_1, Y_2 = train_test_split(X, Y, stratify=Y, test_size=0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with more control, you could use `numpy.random.randint` to generate indices of size of the subset and sample the original arrays as in the following piece of code:

```
# input data, assume that you've 10K samples
In [77]: total_samples = 10000
In [78]: X, Y = np.random.random_sample((total_samples, 784)), np.random.randint(0, 10, total_samples)

# out of these 10K, we want to pick only 500 samples as a subset
In [79]: subset_size = 500

# generate uniformly distributed indices, of size `subset_size`
In [80]: subset_idx = np.random.choice(total_samples, subset_size)

# simply index into the original arrays to obtain the subsets
In [81]: X_subset, Y_subset = X[subset_idx], Y[subset_idx]

In [82]: X_subset.shape, Y_subset.shape
Out[82]: ((500, 784), (500,))
```

Comment: but this does not ensure a balanced class distribution?

Comment: It's uniform sampling of indices. So, in theory it does guarantee uniform sampling

Answer (score 0):

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, stratify=Ture, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

Stratify will ensure the proportion of classes.

If you want to perform K-Fold then

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit
sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=5, test_size=0.5, random_state=0)

for train_index, test_index in sss.split(X, y):
       print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
       X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]
       y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[test_index]
```

check [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html) for sklearn documentaion.